# Iterate through EditText objects

Tags: java, android, iterator

I noticed some redundant code and I thought this was a situation where I could use iteration.  I came up with this solution and emailed my professor.

He replied:

For this example, although the solution works in a limited way, you would need more structure to correctly do what you are trying to do.  What you can do is make an Interface that requires a reset method, have all your controls implement this Interface and supply the reset method, loop through the controls as a collection of the Interface types, and call the reset.

Ok. This kind of makes sense. I know how to implement an interface with a reset method.  However,  "have all your controls implement this interface..loop through the controls" is confusing to me.  Would anyone be able to spell out how I might implement this strategy?

Additionally, if there is a better solution I'm all ears.  Thx!

```
public class MainAddressForm extends AppCompatActivity {

  Button cmdOK;
  Button cmdClear;
  EditText editFirst;
  EditText editLast;
  EditText editAddress;
  EditText editTown;
  EditText editState;
  EditText editZip;

  String first, last, address, town, state, zip;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_address_form);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
      if (cmdOK.getId() == view.getId()) {
        first = editFirst.getText().toString();
        last = editLast.getText().toString();
        address = editAddress.getText().toString();
        town = editTown.getText().toString();
        state = editState.getText().toString();
        zip = editZip.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + first + " " + last + "" + address + " " + town + " " + state + " " + zip + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      if (cmdClear.getId() == view.getId()) {
        setTexts(editFirst, editLast, editAddress, editTown, editState, editZip);
      }
    }

      public void setTexts( EditText first, EditText last, EditText address, EditText town, EditText state, EditText zip){
          List<EditText> clearTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
          Iterator<EditText> itr = clearTextFields.iterator();

          clearTextFields.add(first);
          clearTextFields.add(last);
          clearTextFields.add(address);
          clearTextFields.add(town);
          clearTextFields.add(state);
          clearTextFields.add(zip);

          while(itr.hasNext()){
             itr.next().setText("");
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why your professor told to implement an interface for a reset method, when `EditText`s by default have a reset functionality.

```
mEditText.getText().clear()
```

The above line will clear the text of the `EditText`. As far as I can understand from the above code, you are trying to clear a form (all the `EditText`s) when a button is clicked. The easiest way I can think of is, group the entire form in a single `ViewGroup` (if its not done already). It can be either a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout` and call it say `form_layout`. Then to clear all the `EditText`s in that form, you simply run the following code.

```
private void clearForm(ViewGroup formLayout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < formLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = formLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).getText().clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I will edit the question to include the XML.  It is a Linear Layout.  Thanks.